# List<SelectListItem> - Selected State Getting Cached in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session, caching, selectlistitem

I have an issue i've been working on for the past day and it's driving me crazy.
I have an MVC 3 application that uses a globalactionfilter.cs to create our dropdowns and stores them in a session variable.  That works great, accept we just found a bug that when you edit an item (which uses a modal and an _edit view) and you save it, if you then click on create, the dropdown values are defaulting to the previous edit's selected states.  I can clear the session variables on save, but that doesn't seem to be the right solution. i'd like to prevent the saving of the state period, so that on each edit controller I don't have to clear the session variables.

Please help me see where I'm Derping!

```
    viewBag.ValidationBaseDescriptions = _AllValidationBaseDescriptions

    private List<SelectListItem> _AllValidationBaseDescriptions
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> retList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ValidationBaseDescriptions"] != null)
            {
                retList = (List<SelectListItem>)HttpContext.Current.Session["ValidationBaseDescriptions"];
            }
            else
            {
                retList = _uiContext.ValidationBases.OrderBy(x => x.Description).Select(o => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = o.Description,
                    Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)o.ID).Trim()
                }).ToList();

                retList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "", Selected = true });

                HttpContext.Current.Session["ValidationBaseDescriptions"] = retList;
            }
            return retList;
        }
    }
```

We are then assigning this to the model like:

```
    model.validationDropdown = viewBag.ValidationBaseDescriptions
```